# Need help creating table inside the table and then link those three ages with the tablelink or take me to next page using save & continue button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am brand new to asp.net MVC and I am having some issues creating a website.

I want to keep one one controlled which is "Project controller"and it has it own View-> Create,Edit,Details,and Delete but want to add different but I want to add two more views in the same controller which will be HR and Accounting so there will be another table inside Project-> View ->Create and it will have these three tabs name Project, Accounting, HR and this first Project tab inside create can be named as Project where they will fill information according to each table.

How can I make this work? I have attached my controller code, and three of the view pages code below.

ProjectController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SNAPAIS.Models;
using SNAPAIS.Utils;

namespace SNAPAIS.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectsController : BaseController
    {
        private AISEntities db = new AISEntities();

        // GET: Projects
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            var projects = db.Projects.Where(p => p.Contract.Id == id).Include(x=> x.Contract).ToList();
            ViewBag.ContractId = id;
            return View(projects);
        }

        // GET: Projects/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(project);
        }

        // GET: Projects/Create
        public ActionResult Create(int contractId)
        {
            Project project = new Project();
            project.Id = 0;
            project.ContractId = contractId;
            return View(project);
        }

        // POST: Projects/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,ContractId,ProjectName,ProjectManager,MODNumber,POP,CurrentYearOfPOP,AwardAmount,FundingBaseYear,OY1,OY2,OY3,OY4,CustomerName,CustomerAddress,CustOfficerName,CustSpeciAddress,CORName,CORAddress,TPOCName,TPOCAddress,IsWDC,IsIDIQ,InvoiceInfo,InvoicePeriod,Schedule,InvoiceSubNote")] Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                project.CreatedDate = LoginInfo.CurrentDate();
                project.CreatedBy = LoginInfo.CurrentUser();

                db.Projects.Add(project);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Accounting", new { projectId = project.Id });
            }

            return View(project);
        }

        // GET: Projects/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.ContractId = new SelectList(db.Contracts, "Id", "ContractName", project.ContractId);
            return View(project);
        }

        // POST: Projects/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,ContractId,ProjectName,ProjectManager,MODNumber,POP,CurrentYearOfPOP,AwardAmount,FundingBaseYear,OY1,OY2,OY3,OY4,CustomerName,CustomerAddress,CustOfficerName,CustSpeciAddress,CORName,CORAddress,TPOCName,TPOCAddress,IsWDC,IsIDIQ,InvoiceInfo,InvoicePeriod,Schedule,InvoiceSubNote,CreatedDate,CreatedBy,ModifiedDate,ModifiedBy")] Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.ContractId = new SelectList(db.Contracts, "Id", "ContractName", project.ContractId);
            return View(project);
        }

        // GET: Projects/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(project);
        }

        // POST: Projects/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            db.Projects.Remove(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        public ActionResult Accounting(int projectId)
        {
            Accounting accounting = new Accounting();
            accounting.Id = 0;
            accounting.ProjectId = projectId;
            return View(accounting);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Accounting([Bind(Include = "Id,ProjectId,NewCPProjectNo,ChargeLevelTimesheet,PLCRate,BillingRate")] Accounting accounting)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                accounting.CreatedBy = LoginInfo.CurrentUser();
                accounting.CreatedDate = LoginInfo.CurrentDate();

                Project project = db.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == accounting.ProjectId).Single();

                db.Accountings.Add(accounting);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = project.ContractId});
            }           
            return View(accounting);
        }

        public ActionResult HR(int projectId)
        {
            HR hR = new HR();
            hR.Id = 0;
            hR.ProjectId = projectId;
            return View(hR);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult HR([Bind(Include = "Id,ProjectId,EmployeeName,Address,StartDate,Organization,CPProjectCode,CSHS,PayRate,AcualRate,ReportingManager,TimesheetApprover,EmailAddress")] HR hR)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                hR.CreatedBy = LoginInfo.CurrentUser();
                hR.CreatedDate = LoginInfo.CurrentDate();

                Project project = db.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == hR.ProjectId).Single();

                db.HRs.Add(hR);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = project.ContractId });
            }
            return View(hR);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

View Code for Project -> Create where I want to create two another table inside it and name them Accounting and HR.

```
    @model SNAPAIS.Models.Project

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Project";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Projects", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/Projects/Create">Project</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/Accounting">Accounting</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/HR">HR</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ContractId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)


                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectManager, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectManager, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectManager, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MODNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MODNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MODNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.POP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.POP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.POP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentYearOfPOP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrentYearOfPOP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurrentYearOfPOP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AwardAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AwardAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AwardAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FundingBaseYear, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FundingBaseYear, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FundingBaseYear, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OY1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OY1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OY1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OY2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OY2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OY2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OY3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OY3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OY3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OY4, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OY4, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OY4, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustOfficerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustOfficerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustOfficerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustSpeciAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustSpeciAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustSpeciAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CORName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CORName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CORName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TPOCAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TPOCAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TPOCAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsWDC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsWDC)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsWDC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsIDIQ, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsIDIQ)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsIDIQ, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceInfo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvoiceInfo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoiceInfo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoicePeriod, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvoicePeriod, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoicePeriod, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Schedule, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Schedule, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Schedule, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceSubNote, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvoiceSubNote, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoiceSubNote, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">

                <button type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-default">
                    Save & Continue
                </button>

                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Edit", "Projects")
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Code for Accounting view file

```
    @model SNAPAIS.Models.Accounting

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Accounting";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Accounting", "Projects", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/Project/Create">Project</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/Accounting">Accounting</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/HR">HR</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectId)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewCPProjectNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewCPProjectNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewCPProjectNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

           </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">

            <button type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-default">
                Save & Continue
            </button>

            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Accounting")
        </div>
          </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}


Code for HR view file 

    @model SNAPAIS.Models.HR

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add HR";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("HR", "Projects", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
         <div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/Create">Project</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/Accounting">Accounting</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/HR">HR</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectId)

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectId, "ProjectId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("ProjectId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">

                <button type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "HR")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

[image]

Comment: What you are asking for is a big task. You should probably mention where you are having problems being specific to each module. You should also separate your `View`, `Model` and `Controller` code in separate portions in your question. Putting all the code in one block does not help the readers.

Comment: Hello Rahul: Thanks for correcting me I did separate my code and I understand its a big task but I want to let you know that I have already kept all the elements there and all I need help with them is to just see what it is not working and link these pages inside table

Comment: Okay, can you be more specific as to what your problem is? Can you explain it using your code blocks where you are having problems? If this question is for a code review, then you can post it on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RahulSharma: To be honest I don't know exactly where I have made mistake or what I did wrong that I am not able to connect all tables inside the create table. I can attach screenshot of the tables the way it looks

Comment: Okay, please attach your current output and your desired output.